# Trouble with array and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone explain, why I'm getting an error, when I'm removing items from an array? It works once, but then it crashes. Checked - is boolean meaning.

```javascript
  removeCards = () => {
        console.clear();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.cards.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.state.cards[i]);
            if (this.state.cards[i].checked) {
                delete this.state.cards[i];
            }
        }
        this.setState({ cards: this.state.cards });
    };
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Try using `filter` like this `this.setState({ cards: this.state.cards.filter(elm => !elm.checked)});`

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined".Filter helped me but not at all.It works once and then it "filtering" neighboring elements in array

Comment: @Freeman The issue happens because when you delete from the array the indexes will get messed up, To fix this you can remove `i++` from the for loop and add an else and move the `i++` to the else, or use `filter` as @Adil Bimzagh noted above.

Answer (score 3):

In React, state is immutable.  So instead of trying to alter it directly, create a copy of it and then apply that to state -

```
  removeCards = () => {
        console.clear();
        const newCards = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.cards; i++) {
            if (!this.state.cards[i].checked) {
                newCards.push(this.state.cards[i];
            }
        }
        this.setState({ cards: newCards });
    };
```

Comment: Looks good, but it's not working. Nothing happening. In case of adding lenght to newCards it work firslty, than it crashes again(

Comment: Updated my answer.  I think there was an issue with removing items from an array while looping through it with `for`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my trouble in that? That's how i'm chaning states from true to false and in reverse.

```html
myFunc = (props) => {
        let num = Number(props);
        num--;
        let cards = [...this.state.cards];
        if (this.state.cards[num].checked) {
            cards[num] = { ...cards[num], checked: false };
        } else {
            cards[num] = { ...cards[num], checked: true };
        }
        this.setState({ cards });
    };
```

Comment: In that case, you can do: `this.setState(this.state.cards.map(card => card.checked = !card.checked)`